# Nativescript command gradlew.bat failed error

Tags: android, angular, typescript, gradle, nativescript

I am trying to build a nativescript app when I run tns run android I get this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.

  > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\Natasha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\aarch64-linux-android-strip''
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Unable to apply changes on device: FA53YYJ05603. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.

I have the gradlew.bat file in my folder Myapp/platforms/android/gladlew.bat

I am new to nativescript and app development

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some files missing in `platform => android` folder. I fixed this issue by removing the Android platform and adding it again by using the below command:

Step 1: Navigate to the project directory. 
Step 2: Run below command to fix the issue

```
tns platform remove android

tns platform add android
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled NDK in android studio SDK manager and it worked.